# Can SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME ever be zero?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, winapi, hover

In my WinForms application I'm using the [`SystemParameters.MouseHoverTimeMilliseconds` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousehovertime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which in turn calls the [`SystemParametersInfo` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the [`SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME` input parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME) (according to ILSpy).

I'm using the returned value of the property to set the interval of some timers in my forms.

This all works well.

Now I'm asking myself whether this could be insufficient because it may be zero (or less) on some "strange" systems. In this case I would have to provide a non-zero fallback.

Since I found no evidence of my assumption, can someone bring some light in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN...

### SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME:

> Retrieves the time, in milliseconds, that the mouse pointer has to
>   stay in the hover rectangle for TrackMouseEvent to generate a
>   WM_MOUSEHOVER message. The pvParam parameter must point to a **UINT**
>   variable that receives the time.

### SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERTIME:

> The time specified should be between USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM and
>   USER_TIMER_MINIMUM. If uiParam is less than USER_TIMER_MINIMUM, the
>   *function will use* **USER_TIMER_MINIMUM**. If uiParam is greater than
>   USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM, the function will be USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM.

### SetTimer function

> If uElapse is less than **USER_TIMER_MINIMUM** (**0x0000000A**), the timeout
>   is set to USER_TIMER_MINIMUM. If uElapse is greater than
>   USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM (0x7FFFFFFF), the timeout is set to
>   USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM.

Comment: Yeah, so how does this answer my question?

Comment: The effective minimum value for `SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERTIME` is `USER_TIMER_MINIMUM`.   This is also the minimum effective value for `SetTimer` as well.  So go ahead and use the timers.

Comment: I can't believe I have to explain this.  The question is can the hover time ever be equal to or less than zero?  There are three pieces of evidence to figure it out.  `1.` SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME returns a `UINT`.  UINT has a minimum value of zero.  So now we need to know if the result can ever actually be zero.  `2.` Looking at SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERTIME shows us that the effective lower bound is `USER_TIMER_MINIMUM`.  `3.` Looking at `SetTimer` shows us that `USER_TIMER_MINIMUM` is a constant with a decimal value of `10`.  **So the final answer is SPI_GETMOUSEHOVERTIME can never be less than 10.**